# Eigen Library Speed Up Matrix Initialization

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way to speed up the running time of the following code?

```
Matrix<double, 10, Dynamic> A(10,n);
A << a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10;
```

Here, n is only known at runtime, and a1, a2, and so on are vectors of length n. I've tried to approximate the max size of the matrix and then to use *double, 10, Dynamic, 0, 10, 10000* but this did not give any increase in speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a RowMajor matrix for A, then the copies will be much faster thanks to better cache coherence and vectorization:

```
Matrix<double,10,Dynamic,RowMajor> A(10,n);
```

However, this might also slow down other operations.

Finally, make sure you compiled with optimizations on (e.g., -O2 with gcc), and it might be slightly faster to avoid the comma initializer syntax with:

```
A.row(i) = a_i;
```

(not sure because that depends on the compiler, but that's worth trying if that copy is a bottleneck)

Comment: Thanks!! I'd already done the last two things. The first thing you mentioned brought a great speed increase.